# Looking for fix

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

`npx create-react-app online exam`

npx: installed 98 in 34.58s

Creating a new React app in /home/oem/online.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.24.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "11.0.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.

my node version-: node -v
v14.8.0

my npm version-: npm -v
6.14.8

Comment: eslint is not compatible with your current node version which is 11.0.0, you need one of these: ^8.10.0 or ^10.13.0 or (11.10.1 and above!). try upgrading node.

Answer (score 0):

The `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` package only supports `Active LTS` and `Maintenance LTS` of Node releases. You are using the Node version of `v14.8.0` which is not an LTS version.

According to `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` [docs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint#supported-node-version)

> This project makes an effort to support Active LTS and Maintenance LTS release statuses of Node according to Node's release document. Support for specific Current status releases are considered periodically.

More information about Node's release can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/). Try switching an LTS version of the Node. The latest LTS versions can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).